# Is there any Node js Same Packages that can sends OTP for both email and Phone according to user choice after user hit Forgot Password option?

Tags: node.js, twilio, nodemailer, one-time-password, forgot-password

Suppose,User hit forgot password, now what is the logic to send OTP in email or phone according to user choice? I found nodemailer for sending OTP in email and Twilio for sending OTP in phone,Is there any common packages that helps to send OTP in both email and phone?

Note: User data is saved in Mongodb database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Twilio Verify](https://www.twilio.com/verify) for that purpose, it provides voice, sms, push, and email as channels for 2FA.